# Powershell script to audit new AD accounts & groups

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a *powershell* to audit new created accounts & groups and who created them. The objects are created by account operators, but they are not domain admins.

I think something like this:

```
$Last = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1);
Get-Acl | Get-ADUser -Filter {WhenCreated -ge $Last} | FL DistinguishedName, Path,owner
```

But this doesn't work yet.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Why not use native EventLog events? [Event IDs when a New User Account is Created on Active Directory](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17055.event-ids-when-a-new-user-account-is-created-on-active-directory.aspx)

Comment: We have a lot of domain controllers and the eventlogs are overwritten within a day, so that's not an option.

Comment: Your code works if you remove `Get-ACL |` from the left side. :)

Comment: That might be the case but performance wise it could be less of a burden to have a script that runs every n minutes to just grab the latest events. In addition there are options to ship the event logs to another server. As Craig said it should work if you remove the `Get-ACL`.

Answer (score 0):

This one liner will let you know about the changes after a certain date. There is a ***whenchanged*** property with which you can filter down the objects.

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'whenchanged -gt $dte' | Group-Object objectclass
```

then you can use :

```
get-adgroup -filter *  | sort name | select Name

Get-adgroupmember "Name"
```

or

```
Get-ADGroup -filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" –properties Member | 
Select Name,@{Name="Members";
Expression={($_.member | Measure-Object).count}},
GroupCategory,GroupScope,Distinguishedname |
Out-GridView -Title "Select one or more groups to export" -OutputMode Multiple |
foreach {
  Write-Host "Exporting $($_.name)" -ForegroundColor cyan
  #replace spaces in name with a dash
  $name = $_.name -replace " ","-"
  $file = Join-Path -path "C:\work" -ChildPath "$name.csv"
  Get-ADGroupMember -identity $_.distinguishedname -Recursive |
  Get-ADUser -Properties Title,Department |
  Select Name,Title,Department,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName |
  Export-CSV -Path $file -NoTypeInformation
Get-Item -Path $file
}
```

Comment: The definition for `$dte` is missing. It's likely that it's the same as `$Last` from the OP but it could improve the answer to include it.